# What is correct approach to passing function to AsyncRelayCommand using (MVVM Toolkit)

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

### What is correct way to pass Anonymous function to AsyncRelayCommand ?

let's say I have code like this:

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Input;
//Other usings & namespace..

public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    //Services injections..

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        Approach1 = new AsyncRelayCommand (() => SomeAsyncMethod(parameter));
        Approach2 = new AsyncRelayCommand (async () => await SomeAsyncMethod(parameter));
    }

    public AsyncRelayCommand Approach1 { get; }
    public AsyncRelayCommand Approach2 { get; }

    private async Task SomeAsyncMethod(object param)
    {            
        await _someService.DoSomethingAsync(param);
    }
}
```

which approach is correct ?
And why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct. Here's the difference and what it implies.

Approach 1 generates less lowered code because it doesn't use async await (and therefore doesn't generate the code of the associated state machine). You could see it as the more "efficient" option in terms of speed, memory allocations, and package size.

Approach 2 generates more lowered code because it does use async await (and therefore generates the code of the associated state machine). You may want to use this option if you want the most complete stack trace.

In case of an exception, approach 2 should allow you to see the `SomeViewModel` constructor in the stack trace and approach 1 probably doesn't.

###### What would I choose?

In this case, I would go with approach 1 because the extra stack trace information is not really relevant considering that you would already have `SomeAsyncMethod` in it.